# Should I check for user authorization in every page and request?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I created a system that uses username/password login system with with 'phpass' class to store hashes and check passwords when user logs in.

I also use AJAX to load user information (that can only be retrieved if user is logged) with javascript.

My question is, should I check for user's authentication in every page and in every file that returns AJAX values or just create  a 'connection' entry in MySQL database.

Is it wrong to use 'phpass' functions in every page and request because of performance or is it wrong to use the database method?

What's the best method to keep user connected and check in every page if the user is logged?

Comment: Use PHP `$_SESSION` to store if the user is logged in or not.  Only send credentials on the login page.  Check every page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `$_SESSION` and check it on every page

i.e.

`$loggedIn = ($_SESSION['logged_in']) ? TRUE : FALSE;`

```
if($loggedIn == TRUE){
    //Do stuff here for a logged in user...}`
```

Comment: Why bother with the true false bit if the variable is already a boolean?

Comment: True (pardon the pun). I did it for the sake of clarity. But you're right it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you include some config file in header or some other file, which is available on whole website then check in that file for logged in session, rather adding code to every page